# Directory of publicly available polling data

Tags: api, politics, polling

I'm looking for (US) polling data, mainly presidential polling, for which the full source is available to work with. Specifically, I'm looking to be able to see results broken down by age groups.

Huffington Post offers a nice [API](http://elections.huffingtonpost.com/pollster/api#polls), but I'm wondering if there might be other sources out there.

Comment: http://www.pewresearch.org/data/download-datasets/ has some

Answer (score 2):

Google Consumer Surveys is very open with their data. You can see their reporting [here](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/#/org//reporting/0B29GVb5ISrT0TGk1TW5tVF9Ed2M/page/YgS) and the archive of all their polling (with CSVs containing each individual response) [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0B29GVb5ISrT0VzFQWjFSWGcyeVE).

Otherwise, most pollsters keep their raw data close to their chest, and only release their analysis of their data. Check out FiveThirtyEight's [national poll listings](http://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2016-election-forecast/national-polls/), which include links to the original source for every poll (usually it's just a PDF or a news article though).